# Laravel facing issue in Redirecting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i am working on PTC script where i am facing problem.when i view  third page or second page ads then after confirming ad it will automatically redirect back to ads  page but i want to redirect it back to the current page(for example if i view second page ad then after confirm it has to redirect to second page)
Here's the code.

UserAdvert Controller.php

```
    session()->flash('message', 'This Ads Has Been Successfully Viewed.');
    Session::flash('type', 'success');
    Session::flash('title', 'Earn Successful');


    return redirect()->route('userCash.links');


}
public function cashLinkShow($id)
{

    $advert= Advert::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.viewads.showads', compact('advert'));

}
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('user/cash/links', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinks')->name('userCash.links');
Route::get('user/cash/link/show/{id}', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinkShow')->name('userCashLinks.show');
Route::get('user/cash/link/confirm/{id}', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinkConfirm')->name('userCashLink.confirm');
Route::get('user/cash/links?page=links', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinkPage')->name('userCash.links.page');
```

Site is redirecting to this address after viewing ads

Route::get('user/cash/links', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinks')->name('userCash.links');

but i want to redirect back to the current page from where ad is view i created route for this

Route::get('user/cash/links?page', 'UserAdvertsController@cashLinkPage')->name('userCash.links.page');

but i don't know how to get parameter of paginated page.. kindly help me to resolve this issue.I am beginner in laravel thanks

Comment: Thanks but it does not help it's showing error

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
use Redirect;

return Redirect::to('/user/cash/links');
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Just another way to redirect